# Android : best practice for freeTrial vs payingComplete in Eclipse

Tags: android, database, eclipse, google-play

My android application needs a small database that I load from a parsed sql file stored in the assets.

In the Google Playstore, I've put a free trial version of my app and a complete paying one.
The only difference between them is the size of the database, the app name (insert free in the free one) and the logo ("free" watermark), so the code and resources are 99% reusable.

Using Eclipse, I have to create 2 projects (for the package names to be different) and then copy the code of each class from one project to the other when I update my app.
It is very long and boring because I cannot just copy-paste the entire package.

Is there a way to do this efficiently ?

Thanks !

PS : my title is not very good, I know, if you have any better idea i'll correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite easily in Android Studio using flavours (although it's spelt the US English way flavors).

It's very easily done in your Gradle build file:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        // Set some options
    }
    paid {
        // Set some options
    }
}
```

Android Studio can import your Eclipse project, if you want to take this route.

Comment: Thx, I'll try Android Studio, that's interesting !

Comment: It's a vast improvement form Eclipse, highly recommended!